# Binding a ComboBox to a DataSource Belonging to Another Class

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, combobox

I'm currently building an application that utilizes a ComboBox to allow the user to select from a dynamic list of String objects contained within a BindingList object. However, the BindingList is a member of a child class belonging to the main class, which appears to be causing some issues.

When the ComboBox's data source is set initially within the main class via:

```
this.comboBox.DataSource = this.childClass.dataList;
```

the contents of the ComboBox appear as expected. However, when the contents of the list changes, the contents of the ComboBox are not updated.

If the BindingList object belongs to the main class, the ComboBox updates without any issues. It would appear that the parent class is not receiving the events that signal that the list has been updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at a similar question I asked (and answered) last year:

[Adding/Removing COM Ports from a ComboBox in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645069/adding-removing-com-ports-from-a-combobox-in-c-sharp/6670441#6670441)

, it seems I've (re)discovered the solution. The problem was with how the strings were being added to the data source. Because the list was being augmented in another thread, there was an issue with the ComboBox control being updated. By utilizing a delegate and the Invoke() method, the contents of the ComboBox are now updated as expected.